# Not an editor command: NERDTreeTabsToggle

Tags: vim, vi

I'm absoloutly new to VIM. recently configured .vimrc as below:

```
" plugins
let need_to_install_plugins = 0
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
    silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
        \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
    let need_to_install_plugins = 1
endif

call plug#begin("~/.vim/plugged")
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug 'https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim.git'
Plug 'ap/vim-buftabline'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plug 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plug 'lepture/vim-jinja'
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plug 'alvan/vim-closetag'
Plug 'maxmellon/vim-jsx-pretty'
call plug#end()
```

[Complete .vimrc file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/miguelgrinberg/527bb5a400791f89b3c4da4bd61222e4/raw/e450e5a649d27e7c4de267c9adb0d154675e00d6/.vimrc)

After reloading vim I installed all plugins using :PlugInstall.

But when I run \n to open folder structure it shuts an error:
**E492: Not an editor command:     NERDTreeTabsToggle**

What is the problem?

Comment: That is weird! I suppose you reloaded Vim again after `:PlugInstall` as well?

Comment: Installing 17 plugins is not exactly the most sensible way to start with Vim.

Comment: @j1-lee I'm not sure. What's the problem with reloading?

Comment: @romani I agree. I just wanted to feel working with Vim to learn in from scratch.

Comment: @TheMir I mean reloading is not a problem, but rather maybe you _should_ reload Vim after doing `:PlugInstall`. (Not _right_ after, but the plugins are expected to work well.) But I guess you (correctly) did that.

Comment: Hard to get a feel for Vim if you hide it behind so many plugins. Anyway, could you add the output of `:scriptnames` after startup to your question?

Answer (score 1):

install vim-plug at nvim dir
and

Do this-
**call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/')**